# dynamic re-size of a drawing area

Tags: java, swing, plot, awt

I wrote a program that prints coordinates from GPS onto the screen as a scatter points.
here is the code:

```
class POSCanvas extends JPanel{
    int cnt = 1;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<Vector2D> pnts = new ArrayList<Vector2D>();

    public void getNewPoint (double xnew, double ynew){
        Vector2D pnt = new Vector2D(cnt*xnew, cnt*ynew);
        pnts.add(pnt);
        cnt++;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        if (!pnts.isEmpty()){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g2.setColor(Color.white);
            Dimension size = getSize();
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int w =  size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
            int h =  size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;
            for (int i = 0; i < pnts.size(); i++ ){
                Ellipse2D.Double OV = new Ellipse2D.Double(pnts.get(i).getX() % w, size.height - pnts.get(i).getY() % h, 5, 5);
                g2.draw(OV);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the problem with the drawing is that when the coordinates are bigger then the panel size the drawing makes no sense, the plotting starts from the left side again. here is an example:
[image]

I'd like to dynamically re-size the panel so the coordinates will always stay with its boundaries. How can I do that?

Comment: Assuming you can calculate the amount of space you need, you could override the `getPreferredSize` method of the `JPanel` and return the amount of space you want.  Alternatively, you could calculate the scaling factor (between what you want and what you have) and scale the points accordinginly

Comment: i think the scaling part is what i am looking for because the number could get pretty big and i can not re-size that window forever. any idea about how should i do the scaling ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"scale the points accordinginly"* An `AffineTransform` at render-time would be my choice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It would depend on the effect you want to get, if you wanted the "points" to the same size, just closer, then scaling the coordinates would be the way go

Comment: @DanyLavrov You'll probably want to do some research in [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html). Scaling can be done in a number of ways, you could just scale the `Graphics` context using an `AffineTransform` or if you want to maintain the "points" at the same size, simply scale the coordinates